# FIlter alassets by year

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary

I'm trying to filter AlAssets by year and month. I can already get the dates and filter by year and month, but it's too slow with about 1000 photos. What's the best way to do it?

```
+ (void) loadFromLibraryByDate:(ALAssetsLibrary *)library assetType:(NSString *)type toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array onTable:(UITableView *)tableView onYear:(NSString *)year onMonth:(NSString *)mouth withDelegate:(id) delegate{

//clean passed objects
[array removeAllObjects];

// filter for the library
NSInteger groupType = ALAssetsGroupAll;



// block to enumerate thought the groups
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock =
^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
    if(group){
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if(asset){
                //                    cachedPhotos = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                if([asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] == type){
                    if(year != nil && mouth != nil)
                    {
                        NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                        if(date.year == [year integerValue] && date.month == [mouth integerValue])
                        {
                            [array addObject:asset];
                        }
                     }
                    else if(year != nil && mouth == nil)
                    {
                        NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                        NSString *monthName = [date monthName:date.month];
                        if(date.year == [year integerValue])
                        {
                            if(![array containsObject:monthName])
                            {
                                [array addObject:monthName];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                        NSNumber *yearNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:date.year];
                        if(![array containsObject:yearNum])
                        {
                            [array addObject:yearNum];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
    }
    else{
        if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishLoadingLibraryByDate:)] ){
            [delegate performSelector:@selector(didFinishLoadingLibraryByDate:)];
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
};

// failure block, what happens if when something wrong happens when enumerating
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failBlock = ^(NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *libraryFailure = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Serviço de Localização" message:@"Para poder partilhar conteúdos nesta versão iOS, tem de autorizar os serviços de localização. (Definições > Serviços de Localização)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [libraryFailure show];
            [libraryFailure release];
        });

    });

};

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupType usingBlock:listGroupBlock failureBlock:failBlock];
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.  There is no way I know of to filter on metadata except by enumerating the way you are doing it.  Unfortunately, enumerating through asset groups is just inherently slow on iOS -- if you think 1000 is bad, try 10k or 20k assets (not at all uncommon, I have that on my carry phone right now).

One way around this (not necessarily advised, as it's a lot of work and the bug potential is very high) is to build your own database of asset timestamps.  While the user is otherwise busy (with a tutorial or something), enumerate over all the assets and copy the metadata and `ALAssetPropertyAssetURL` to whatever format works best for you.  Don't forget to listen for `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` messages if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought that was a better way to do it. I think it's something that I will have to live with

Answer (score 0):

You should enumerate all ALAsset first When App launching,and then filter them. Because Enumerating ALAsset from database is so slow, so you should not reenumerate them again.
Therer is a notice, reenumerate ALAsset more faster then the first. Apple should optimize the library.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It's really slow to enumerate all AlAssets. I will try your approach