# Get today's photo from album in IOS

Tags: ios, photo

Is there any way to get only today's photos from album in ios？ 
I know how to get album but all photos displayed as timeline.
I want to get only today's photos or last two days' photo, how can I realized that?
Thanks.

Comment: Do it using the AssetLibrary framework: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575691/filter-alassets-by-year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this snippet to get today's photo, which works on iOS 8. I originally filtered the assets from Recently Added album, which stores photos from last 30 days or 1000 photos. There is a chance user captures more than 1000 photos in two days, so I changed the code to get all photos from the library.

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %d",PHAssetMediaTypeImage];

PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];

//get day component of today
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentDay = dayComponent.day;

//get day component of yesterday
dayComponent.day = - 1;
NSDate *yesterdayDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSInteger yesterDay = [[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:yesterdayDate] day];

//filter assets of today and yesterday add them to an array.
NSMutableArray *assetsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (PHAsset *asset in assetsFetchResult) {
    NSInteger assetDay = [[calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:asset.creationDate] day];

    if (assetDay == currentDay || assetDay == yesterDay) {
        [assetsArray addObject:asset];
    }
    else {
        //assets is in descending order, so we can break here.
        break;
    }
}
```

Prior iOS 8, using ALAssetsLibrary, suppose you have a photo group, enumerate the group in reverse order, and do the similar thing as above.

```
[self.photoGroup enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
      NSDate *date = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
  }];
```

Comment: don't just trow some code here. at least add a short sentence explaining WHY it does what it does. - also mention this is only for ios8

Answer (score 12):

Swift 3 version with a range of dates:

```
let fromDate = // the date after which you want to retrieve the photos
let toDate // the date until which you want to retrieve the photos 

let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@ && creationDate < %@", fromDate as CVarArg, toDate as CVarArg)

//Just a way to set order
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
options.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

return PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: options)
```

Comment: You have typo in second argument type.

Comment: Thanks. That lasted long. :)

Comment: You just change it wrong. "CVarArg" was correct, just in second parameter you had "CVarGArg". Sorry for misunderstanding ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a predicate for the day

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

NSPredicate *predicateMediaType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %d",PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] beginningOfDay];
NSPredicate *predicateDate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creationDate >= %@", date];

NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateDate, predicateMediaType]];


allPhotosOptions.predicate = compoundPredicate;

PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:allPhotosOptions];
```

Where

```
@implementation NSDate (Utils)

- (NSDate *)beginningOfDay {
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:CYCalendarUnitYear | CYCalendarUnitMonth | CYCalendarUnitDay fromDate:self];

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Comment: This is actually a much better answer than the accepted one. It doesn't need to fetch all the images and then filter them out. and with just one line of code. :)